# TM symbol, gets converted to junk characters 'â„¢' while saving data to PostgreSQL

Tags: python, json, postgresql, unicode, encoding

I am calling a rest endpoint which returns the data in JSON format, then I do json.loads(response), which gives me a dictionary, I do some pre-processing here, but not touching the keys where it has TM symbol in the string. Then I call another rest endpoint to save this dictionary where I make use of json.dumps(dictionary) in order to prepare the request data.

```
x = '{ "name":"Java™ SE Development Kit 17.0.1 (JDK 17.0.1)", "age":30, "city":"New York"}'

# parse x:
y = json.loads(x)

y['age'] = 45

z = json.dumps(y)

request['data'] = z

#calling the API to store the data to PostgreSQL where it's getting saved as 'Javaâ„¢ SE Development Kit 17.0.1..'
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: It's python

Comment: Somewhere it's being decoded incorrectly.  Is the correct encoding set on the request to the API?  It might be worth setting `ensure_ascii=True` when you call `json.dumps` if the remote side has trouble with non-ascii characters

Comment: 1) Is the TM symbol preserved in `z`? 2) What is the encoding of the Postgres database? Check with `show client_encoding;` and `show server_encoding`. Add answers as update to your question.